# How do I check if view controller is initial view controller? (SWIFT 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, root

In the storyboard, there's a property in the inspector pane which says "Is Initial View Controller". How do I access this property programmatically? I don't want to change it. I just want to check if the view controller is currently the initial view controller. I've specified conditions in the AppDelegate under which it should turn the view controller into the root view controller. Once it actually is the root view controller, I want to run some code from the view controller itself (but ONLY when it IS the root view controller). So I can't just run the code from the ViewDidLoad method. I want to check if the view controller is the root view controller first, and if it is, THEN I want to run some code. Any ideas?

Comment: I would reword this question - what you are really looking for is a way to check what the current rootViewController is, rather than anything to do with a storyboard's initial vc.

Comment: You can try to tag the view of the root viewcontroller, and check the tag/view after that.

Comment: @BJHStudios yeah, sorry that's not what I meant. Didn't realize what the significant difference between these two things were, but I'm looking for a way to check what the initial view controller (view controller that gets displayed first after app finishes launching). Might also have to change the code inside the AppDelegate, because I just set my VC as its rootViewController while all I wanted to do is set it as the initial VC which gets displayed first.

Comment: the code in my answer will let you check the current rootVC at any time. what gets displayed first depends a lot on your setup. 

For example, if you are using a navigation controller, the nav controller might be the app's rootVC, but you might want the rootVC of the nav controller, which is what is being displayed.

Comment: @BJHStudios and is there no way of just modifying the "Is Initial View Controller" property in the storyboard programmatically? It's kinda weird I can't find that property, because normally all the properties you can modify in the storyboard can also be modified programmatically.

Comment: no, that's not an accessible property programmatically. but even if you could modify it, all that would do is change which type of view controller is instantiated when calling the instantiateInitialViewController method on the storyboard. It would not change the current view hierarchy.

Comment: "How do I access this property programmatically" The question itself has a Bad Smell. You should think more about _why_ you think you need to know this, and modify your architecture accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The initial view controller from a storyboard is not the same as the root view controller for the app. You may have multiple storyboards, for instance, each with their own initial view controllers. Some piece of code may have changed the current rootViewController as well, making it different from the initial view controller launched from the app.

To check if a current view controller is the root view controller, use this:

```
    if self == UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        /*do stuff*/
    }
```

Be careful about where you place this, though. I would do the check in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: @FreddyBenson: This is the correct answer. If it answers your question, please select it as the correct answer.